# Tcpdf auto set persheet

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

i have successfully generated pdf using tcpdf
now i want to make that one page to 4 page in one sheet

[image]

there is no problem with the script...i just want to make it auto set persheet 4 so the user dont have to configure the setting each time they want to print..is there a way to do this so that i dont have to change my coding to much

---

as suggested, i use fpdi

```
             $pdf->Output($st.'/TEST.PDF', 'F');
            require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/FPDI/fpdf_tpl.php');
            require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/FPDI/fpdi.php');


            $filename = $st.'/TEST.PDF';

            $pdfx = new FPDI();


            //exit();

            $pageCount = $pdfx->setSourceFile($filename);


            //echo $pageCount;
            //exit();

            $w = $pdfx->GetPageWidth() / 2 - 15;
            $h = 0;

            $_x = $x = 10;
            $_y = $y = 10;

            $pdfx->AddPage();
            for ($n = 1; $n <= $pageCount; $n++) {
                $tplIdx = $pdfx->importPage($n);

                $size = $pdfx->useTemplate($tplIdx, $x, $y, $w);
                $pdfx->Rect($x, $y, $size['w'], $size['h']);
                $h = max($h, $size['h']);
                if ($n % 2 == 0) {
                    $y += $h + 10;
                    $x = $_x;
                    $h = 0;
                } else {
                    $x += $w + 10;
                }

                if ($n % 4 == 0 && $n != $pageCount) {
                    $pdfx->AddPage();
                    $x = $_x;
                    $y = $_y;
                }
            }

            $pdfx->Output('thumbnails.pdf', 'F');
```

but im getting a error message

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(): remote host file access not supported, file://thumbnails.pdf

Filename: include/tcpdf_static.php

Line Number: 2466
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(file://thumbnails.pdf): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

Filename: include/tcpdf_static.php

Line Number: 2466
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: thumbnails.pdf

is this a conflict libraries in codeignighter? i load tcpdf then i require once fpdi libraries

---

oh i think i know the problem is about the saving location... nevermind i re-edit my Output to 
$pdfx->Output('thumbnails.pdf', 'I');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a prepress term — [imposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imposition) — for what you're talking about. I guess TCPDF itself doesn't have imposition tools.

You could write a simple imposition tool using FPDI on the file generated by TCPDF (check [this example](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/thumbnails/#p-175) out), or take a look at another library called [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/) and, to be specific,
 [pdfimpose](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdf-import/pdfimpose/php-pdfimpose/) script for that library.

Comment: ok i use fpdi as u suggested but im getting a error message, but i think the code is working..its only the part when i try to output the thumbnails.pdf i dont know why its getting libraries from tcpdf

Comment: oh i know the problem i just reedit to $pdfx->Output('thumbnails.pdf', 'I');